# Tricky loop through database entries in a JAVA method

Tags: java, loops, nested-loops

I'd like to loop through the following table (this loop is not the problem)
[image]

The method should return "success" to me, if one of the items with the same IDs (ID1 and ID2) is on success and all other items are also on success. See the picture above one 7 - 7 is on failed and one 7 -7 is on success so this should return success. But only, if the other entry in the db (ID1 = 7  and ID2 = 8) is also on success.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: wht you have tried so far?

Comment: It would make more sense to create a proper query which selects only the row which have *success* as their `Status`.

Comment: I have done it like: Loop through all the entries with a for loop, then check what the status of the first item is, if it is success then set a boolean to true, if not set the boolean to false, this works when you have only different status for different ID1 and ID2's ...i fail to get it done when there are two entries with the same ID1 and ID2...

Comment: how do you determine what "the other entry in the db" is?

Comment: Btw your question is unclear: first you say *"The method should return "success" to me, if one of the items with the same IDs (ID1 and ID2) is on success."* and then *"But only, if the other entry in the db (ID1 = 7 and ID2 = 8) is also on success."*. That doesn't match.

Comment: That's definitly something you should do in DB. There should be no need to transfer data to Java land and then iterate through it.

Comment: @JB Nitzet, thats the problem if i loop, it is not possible to determine that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use query like

```
select status from table1 where table1.ID1= table1.ID2;
```

than after you should check status for `success` or `failure` in your for loop